String augmentation and concatenation in ANTLR
I am having issues with ANTLR augmented strings.
My main issue is if I want augmentedStrings to be read right, i have to keep string as a parser rule.
But this causes the string to have quote, body, if there are any, body continued and end quote.
This makes the implementation of a visitor more difficult.
When i exchange the string rule to
string: STRING; STRING: QUOTE ( ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | .)*? QUOTE;
it breaks the augmentedString, which is already "hackish".
Down below is the grammar.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
The test command used is: antlr4-parse strings.g4 root -gui <test1.txt
and the test1.txt holds: string a = "normal string" + $"{id}";
grammar strings;

// Comments and white space
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

// key words
PLUS: '+';
// Symbols
QUESTION: '?';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LCURLY: '{';
RCURLY: '}';
SEMI: ';';
NEWLINE: '\n';
ASSIGN: '=';
QUOTE: '"';
DOLLAR: '$';

// Types
STRING_T: 'string';
type: STRING_T;

value:
    | augmentedString
    | concatanatedString
    | string;

//this has to be changed to a lexer rule inorder to not have a child of every thing
string: 
QUOTE ( ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | .)*? QUOTE;
 
augmentedString:
    DOLLAR QUOTE (( ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | .)?( LCURLY expr RCURLY) | ( ESCAPE_SEQUENCE | .)( LCURLY expr RCURLY)?  ) * QUOTE;

concatanatedString: (id | augmentedString | string ) (PLUS (id | augmentedString | string))*;

ESCAPE_SEQUENCE:
    '\\' (('\\' | '\'' | '"' ) | UNICODE_ESCAPE);
fragment UNICODE_ESCAPE:
    'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT;
fragment HEX_DIGIT: [0-9a-fA-F];
// Identifiers
ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
id: ID;
argument: type id; //maybe replace all with the right hand side.

field: type? id ASSIGN expr SEMI;

// Expressions
expr:
     id
    |value;
// Statements
statementList: statement*;

statement:
    field;


// Add a start rule for testing
root: (
    field
    )*;


I have attempted to change the string rule to a parser rule, with the extra step, as well as a bunch of hackish solutions such as splitting the string into a quote and a string body and having a seperate end body.

Antlr lexers are fully context free. Any parser rules can be moved from the parser to lexer, with the restriction that the rules are all marked as fragment except the top level lexer rule. You don't need lexer modes. But you will need to rename the parser symols as lexer symbols.

By promoting STRING to string, you will also skip spaces inside string literals because of the WS rule.

You could make use of ANTLR's lexer modes. When you encounter a $", you switch to a special string mode and create tokens specific for an interpolated string. Inside that mode, you again switch to a "code mode" when you encounter a {. You pop back from this code mode after encountering a } and again pop back to the default mode when you encounter a ".
To use modes, you must separate the lexer- and parser grammars in separate files. A quick demo:
// File: ModeDemoLexer.g4
lexer grammar ModeDemoLexer;

PLUS           : '+';
SIMPLE_STRING  : '"' ~["\r\n]* '"';
STRING_START   : '$"' -> pushMode(STRING_MODE);
SPACES         : S+ -> skip;

fragment S     : [ \t\r\n];

mode STRING_MODE;

STRING_END     : '"' -> popMode;
CODE_START     : '{' -> pushMode(CODE_MODE);
STRING_ATOM    : ~["{];

mode CODE_MODE;

CODE_MODE_SKIP : S+ -> skip;
ID             : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
CODE_END       : '}' -> popMode;

and:
// File: ModeDemoParser.g4
parser grammar ModeDemoParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=ModeDemoLexer;
}

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : expr PLUS expr
 | string
 | SIMPLE_STRING
 ;

string
 : STRING_START string_atom* STRING_END
 ;

string_atom
 : STRING_ATOM
 | CODE_START code_expr CODE_END
 ;

code_expr
 : ID
 ;

If you now parse "normal string" + $"id: { id }", you get the following result:

And without modes, you could do something like this:
parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : expr PLUS expr
 | string
 | '(' expr ')'
 | SIMPLE_STRING
 | ID
 ;

string
 : STRING_START expr ( STRING_MIDDLE expr )* STRING_END
 ;

PLUS          : '+';
SIMPLE_STRING : '"' ~["\r\n]* '"' | '$"' ~["\r\n{]* '"';
STRING_START  : '$"' ~["{]* '{';
STRING_MIDDLE : '}' ~["{]* '{';
STRING_END    : '}' ~["{]* '"';
SPACES        : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
ID            : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;

Parsing input "normal string" + $"id: { id }, x + y = { (x + y) }" would then result in:


Thank you very much, you truly are an oracle.
